# R- Reading one column, and using qpcr cbind

Tags: r, data.table, cbind

So I am trying to read several csv files, take their first column and create a new file. I have succeeded using qpcR and data.table using the following code:

```
FileNames <- dir(pattern = "*.csv") 

x <- integer()

for (FileName in FileNames) {
  data <- read.csv(file = FileName, header=FALSE, skip=1)

  y <- data[,1]

  x<-qpcR:::cbind.na(x, y)

  rm(data)
}

write.csv(x, file = 'test.csv')
```

This works fine, however I have discovered that I can read just the first column of my data using the data.table library.

```
x <- integer()
for (FileName in FileNames) {
  data <- fread(FileName,select=1,skip=1, header=FALSE)
  y <- data[1:nrow(data),]
  x<-qpcR:::cbind.na(x, y)
  rm(data)
}

write.csv(x, file = 'test.csv')
```

However this seems to treat y as a data value or integer, which throws up the error:

Error in data.table::data.table(...) : 
  Item 2 has no length. Provide at least one item (such as NA, NA_integer_ etc) to be repeated to match the 11 rows in the longest column. Or, all columns can be 0 length, for insert()ing rows into.

Any help on this would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after investigating using typeof(), that I needed to convert the list generated by fread, to a numeric by adding the following line.

```
data <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
```

This then worked